# How to downgrade Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365

I want to downgrade my Office 365, from `Version 1810, Build 11001.20108` to `Version 1809, Build 10827.20138` / `16.0.10920.20003`

Tried to downgrade with two methods - but both without success:

1. a bat-file, containing `cd %programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRunofficec2rclient.exe /update user updatetoversion=16.0.10920.20003`
2. Download and run Deployment Tool with custom confifuration file, edited to

`<Configuration>
<Updates Enabled="TRUE" TargetVersion="16.0.10920.20003" />
</Configuration>`

Could somebody point me to any working method?

**Update** (could be important): i'm not an administrator, and the Microsoft user, which gets updates, is shared between multiple terminals. Thats why i'm forced to operate only on my computer - operating under Microsoft user would make changes on some terminals beside of mine.

Comment: Are you an Administrator of your Office 365 deployment?

Comment: no, and the user, which gets updates is shared by multiple clients (not only my computer). It means, i can operate only on my computer - because if i operate with Microsoft user the changes would apply on other terminals too.

Comment: If you are not an Administrator of your Office 365 deployments then you don’t have access to what you need to accomplish your task.

Comment: As long as you are an Administrator on the machine you might be able to use the [deployment tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool) but you are going to fight the Office 365 deployment configuration so the modified installation likely will be updated

Comment: What do i need as an Office-Administrator to roll back? Maybe i'll be able to get my admin to cooperate...

Answer (score 4):

I tried the other techniques, but couldn't make them work.

This simple command does the trick for me though:

```
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.10827.20181
```

Answer (score 2):

As Ramhound says, to revert to an earlier version of click-to-run Office 2016 on the computer, it requires Administrator to do it. We can follow the steps below to revert it:

[See Microsofts official documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool)

In Short:

1. Download the [Office Deployment Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49117).
2. Install and extract it to a ODT folder in Desktop. It contains two files: Setup.exe and Configuration.xml.
3. Open Configuration.xml file, edit it with the following text, then save it as a new file **RevertOffice.xml** in the same folder of Setup.exe:

`<Configuration>
<Updates Enabled="TRUE" TargetVersion="16.0.10920.20003" />
</Configuration>`

4. In Windows, click Start, search for cmd, right-click **Command Prompt**, click **Run as Administrator**.
5. Switch to the file location for the Setup.exe file. For example, type `cd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ODT`
6. Run the following command:
   `setup.exe /configure RevertOffice.xml`
7. Start Word 2016, go to File > Account, under Product Information, click **Update Options** > **Update Now**.
8. Check if the Office is reverted to your targeted version.
9. Disable Office Update to avoid it update to higher version: In Word 2016, click **File** > **Account**, under **Product Information**, click **Update Options** > **Disable Updates**.

Comment: as i written in the question, i've tried this method already, without success.

Comment: @Evgeniy Are you tried the steps above with the local administrator account on the computer?

Comment: Sure, des, tried it

Comment: This worked a treat. Had to downgrade from a current monthly security release to the previous month's due to a software incompatibility with Office 365. Executed this script as shown, other than the version change, and it worked first time, perfectly. Thanks @winnil

Answer (score 0):

i do it yesterday, from ver 1904 to 1903...license bussiness premium

that not work for me....after varoius atempts i have to do it from zero

- uninstall office
- download deployment tool
- use https://config.office.com/officeSettings/configure# to configure the xml (here you can choose a pair of versions to downgrade)
- use first, "setup /download" to download locally
- then use "setup /configure" to install

but im interesting in doing directly...