# Finding the TargetVersion for an Office 365 Excel build

Tags: microsoft-excel

I plan to use this [How to downgrade Office 365?](https://superuser.com/questions/1380385/how-to-downgrade-office-365) to set my Excel to a specific version. But from where I can find what I need to put into the TargetVersion when I want my Excel to be in version 1902 build 11328.20392?

I tried to use

```
<Configuration>
  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" TargetVersion="11328.20392" />
</Configuration>
```

But it gave me an error when I tried to make Excel to update.

Edit:
In case it matters. My current Excel version is 1909 (Build 12026.20334 Click-to-Run).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the full version number, like this `16.0.xxxxx.yyyyy`
in your case: `16.0.11328.20392`

see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-downgrade-the-office-365-to-previous/1de70e00-1706-40b8-a1c5-50753812d8df) and [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic)